# Refresh suggestion list on change - cn1 autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, codenameone

I've implemented a custom autocomplete text field in a cn1 app, but I've noticed it only loads the suggestions list once, after that any change in the text doesn't trigger a change in the list, and the `getSuggestionModel()` is never called again.  How can I achieve this (in my mind, basic) functionality?

This is my autocomplete class:

```
public class ForumNamesAutocomplete extends AutoCompleteTextField {
    List<String>suggestions = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<Map<String,Object>> fData;
    StateMachine mac;
    int currentIndex;
    String prevText;
    public static final String KEY_FORUM_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_FORUM_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_FORUM_DESC = "desc";

    public ForumNamesAutocomplete(StateMachine sm){
        super();
        mac = sm;
        if(sm.forumData != null){
            fData = mac.forumData;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean filter(String text) { 
        if(text.equals(prevText)){
            return false;
        }
        setSuggestionList(text);
        fireDataChanged(DataChangedListener.CHANGED, text.length());
        prevText = text;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void fireDataChanged(int type, int index) {
        super.fireDataChanged(type, index);
    }



    public void setSuggestionList(String s){
        if(suggestions == null){
            suggestions = new LinkedList<String>();
        }else{
            suggestions.clear();
        }
        LinkedList<String> descList = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<fData.size();i++){
            boolean used = false;
            Map<String,Object> forumMap = fData.get(i);
            if(((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_NAME)).indexOf(s) != -1){
                suggestions.add((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_NAME));
                used = true;
            }
            if(!used && ((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_DESC)).indexOf(s) != -1){
                descList.add((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_NAME));
            }
        }
        suggestions.addAll(descList);
    }



    @Override
    protected ListModel<String> getSuggestionModel() {
            return new DefaultListModel<String>(suggestions);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional debugging, I saw that the `getSuggestionModel()` method was being called only during initialization, and whatever the suggestion list (in `suggestion` object) was at that point, it remained so.  Instead I needed to manipulate the underlying `ListModel` object:

```
public class ForumNamesAutocomplete extends AutoCompleteTextField {
    ListModel<String>myModel = new ListModel<String>();
    ...

    @Override
    protected boolean filter(String text) { 
        if(text.length() > 1){
            return false;
        }
        setSuggestionList(text);
        return true;
    }

    private void setSuggestionList(String s){
        if(myModel == null){
            myModel = new ListModel<String>();
        }else{
            while(myModel.getSize() > 0)
                myModel.removeItem(0);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<fData.size();i++){
            boolean used = false;
            Map<String,Object> forumMap = fData.get(i);
            if(((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_NAME)).indexOf(s) != -1){
                myModel.addItem((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_NAME));
                used = true;
            }
            if(!used && ((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_DESC)).indexOf(s) != -1){
                myModel.addItem((String)forumMap.get(KEY_FORUM_NAME));
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to be simpler and seems to be a bit problematic now as explained in [this issues](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1694).

Technically what you need to do is return one model and then mutate said model/fire modified events so everything will refresh. This is non-trivial and might not work correctly for all use cases so ideally we should have a simpler API to do this as we move forward.

Comment: So what do I need to add to my implementation/which methods do I need to override for that?

Comment: This is discussed in the issue, this is something we need to improve.